# XSLT - inner join type command for combining two functions

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two functions that are outputting XML data. Ideally I'd like to combine the outputs of each function into one variable to parse data.

In SQL terms, each function can be joined together by an inner join via the attribute PageId... but joins are not permitted in XSLT (or at least to my knowledge).

Any suggestions on the cleanest/easiest way to combine these functions? The functions I'm calling are built into the cms and cannot be edited.

Some more information:

The first function is the sitemap. It lists the webpage ids and their levels for the website.

The second function pulls webpage ids and their metadata tags that I need combined with the site map.

I thought about creating variables for the second function Page Ids, but the number of pages with the metadata tags changes and I don't believe the variables support dynamic names.

I apologize if I'm not being clear enough as xslt is new to me. Please let me know if more information is needed.

edit: adding code example

```
<in:inputs xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
  <in:result name="SitemapXml">
    <Page Id="a0a47ce1-6eba-4d29-a7a3-3749c768c7e7" isopen="true" xmlns="">
      <Page Id="a3055286-0e90-4b04-99dd-fb1a61dde0bf" isopen='true' xmlns="">
        <Page Id="da675b13-d4d3-42ab-acc1-82e2a5408100" isopen='true' iscurrent='true' Depth="2"/>
      </Page>
    </Page>
  </in:result>
  <in:result name="GetisrootXml">
    <isroot PageId="a0a47ce1-6eba-4d29-a7a3-3749c768c7e7" Id="f8d4eea4-7070-4bc3-a804-e106697ffaa9" isroot="true" xmlns=""/>
    <isroot PageId="f8e4adbc-2758-42d6-bc40-0192ba0107a6" Id="db62e132-3f3b-493f-917a-9e090f887f13" isroot="false" xmlns=""/>
  </in:result>
</in:inputs>
```

What I would like returned:

```
<in:inputs xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
  <in:result name="SitemapXml">
    <Page Id="a0a47ce1-6eba-4d29-a7a3-3749c768c7e7" isopen="true" xmlns="" isroot='true'>
    </Page>
    <Page Id="a3055286-0e90-4b04-99dd-fb1a61dde0bf" isopen='true' xmlns="">
        <Page Id="da675b13-d4d3-42ab-acc1-82e2a5408100" isopen='true' iscurrent='true' Depth="2"/>
  </in:result>
</in:inputs>
```

From this, I want to further change the output to fit my needs (add tags for display purposes). In order to get to that point, the isroot attribute needs to be attached to the sitemap.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0, or are you restricted to 1.0? There are some features in 2.0 that would make the task easier.

Comment: Are the two `in:result` Elements really nested, or is this a typo in your code example? And where is the second `Page` element closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kIsRootByPageId" match="isroot" use="@PageId"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="in:result[1]/Page">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kIsRootByPageId',@Id )/@isroot"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="in:result[2]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<in:inputs xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
    <in:result name="SitemapXml">
        <Page Id="a0a47ce1-6eba-4d29-a7a3-3749c768c7e7" isopen="true" xmlns=""></Page>
        <Page Id="a3055286-0e90-4b04-99dd-fb1a61dde0bf" isopen='true' xmlns="">
            <Page Id="da675b13-d4d3-42ab-acc1-82e2a5408100" isopen='true' iscurrent='true' Depth="2"/></Page>
    </in:result>
    <in:result name="GetisrootXml">
        <isroot PageId="a0a47ce1-6eba-4d29-a7a3-3749c768c7e7" Id="f8d4eea4-7070-4bc3-a804-e106697ffaa9" isroot="true" xmlns=""/>
        <isroot PageId="f8e4adbc-2758-42d6-bc40-0192ba0107a6" Id="db62e132-3f3b-493f-917a-9e090f887f13" isroot="false" xmlns=""/>
    </in:result>
</in:inputs>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<in:inputs xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
   <in:result name="SitemapXml">
      <Page Id="a0a47ce1-6eba-4d29-a7a3-3749c768c7e7" isopen="true" isroot="true"/>
      <Page Id="a3055286-0e90-4b04-99dd-fb1a61dde0bf" isopen="true">
         <Page Id="da675b13-d4d3-42ab-acc1-82e2a5408100" isopen="true" iscurrent="true"
               Depth="2"/>
      </Page>
   </in:result>
</in:inputs>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies "as-is" every node for which this template is selected for execution.
2. There are two overriding templates, the second of which "deletes" with its empty body the second occurence of `in:result`.
3. The first overriding template matches any `Page` that is a child of the first occurence of `in:result`. We use keys to efficiently and conveniently find the `isroot` element that references the current `Page` in its `PageId` attribute -- and we copy its `isroot` attribute.

Comment: works perfect! thanks! I'm not familiar with the identity rule or using keys, but I'll google these terms to fully understand how the function is working. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user673869: You are welcome. In my answer there are links to both these techniques -- in particular The XSLT FAQ is one of the best resources on XSLT problem solving methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to reconstruct your requirement from a desription of a solution expressed in SQL terms, since it's so many years since I used SQL in anger. And XSLT is different from SQL, because it uses a hierarchic data model rather than a tabular data model, which means that terms like "inner join" do not map directly. However, it is certainly possible to do joins (both inner and outer) in XSLT: you typically write them as if they were nested loops.

The detailed answer to your question depends on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, and on whether the functions to be composed are delivering XML or atomic values. It's really more effective to ask a specific question with specific example input and output, so that we can give a specific answer.

Comment: We will be using XSLT 1.0. The functions are delivering XML data. I've worked very little in SQL and less with XSLT functions, so I apologize if I'm not clear. I've added some code to my original request.